# Significato di "lo specifico aleatorio dello svincolo"

Tags: meaning

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> GIOVANNI     D’accordo, ma noi qui stiamo facendo un favore... che sennò si ruban tutto.
>   
>   BRIGADIERE     
>   Non abbiamo bisogno di nessun favore... via,
>   sloggiare!
>   
>   GIOVANNI     
>   Volentieri, ma guardi che ce l’aveva detto l’appuntato, quello che sta laggiù a verificare presso il camion.
>   
>   BRIGADIERE     Quale appuntato laggiù?
>   
>   GIOVANNI     
>   Quello che sta facendo **lo specifico aleatorio dello svincolo**.

Il brano si riferisce a un incidente stradale nel quale due camion si erano ribaltati.

Non riesco a capire cosa sta dicendo questo personaggio, Giovanni, quando pronuncia la battuta "Quello che sta facendo lo specifico aleatorio dello svincolo" in riferimento all'appuntato della polizia. Ho cercato alla voce ["aleatorio" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000307.jpg) e immagino che "aleatorio" faccia riferimento a un "contratto aleatorio" (che non so veramente cosa sia). Per quanto riguarda il termine "svincolo", ho trovato il suo significato questo stesso [dizionario](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000636.jpg):

> Nelle  autostrade  e  nelle  superstrade,  l’insieme  dei raccordi   di   allacciamento   alla   viabilità   ordinaria,   in partic.  in  corrispondenza  di  centri  abitati,  o  ad  altre 
>   arterie  di  traffico  veloce;  tratto  di  raccordo  che  per­mette  il  passaggio  di una  corrente  di  traffico  da  una strada ad un'altra.

Veramente si tratta di una definizione che non capisco del tutto bene.

Le diverse accezioni dell'aggettivo "specifico" le ho trovate [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000785.jpg) e [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000786.jpg), ma non so a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel testo.

Allora, la mia domanda sarebbe: cosa significa "fare lo specifico aleatorio dello svincolo" nel passaggio sopra citato?

Comment: La mia è solo una supposizione; credo che stia dicendo che l'appuntato sta verificando quali fattori casuali possano avere causato l'incidente in quella particolare situazione. Ho trovato sul vocabolario Treccani l'uso sostantivato di _specifico_: "lo s., l’elemento singolare, tipico, che distingue e caratterizza un determinato contesto."

Comment: Non è che il personaggio Giovanni dica altri strafalcioni qua e là?

Comment: @egreg:  Si tratta di un operaio, tuttavia a me non sembra che sia un personaggio grossolano.

Comment: @Charo Dire strafalcioni non è necessariamente associato a grossolanità.

Comment: @egreg: Non conosco questa parola, quindi l'ho cercata sul Treccani e ho trovato: "Errore grossolano, nel parlare o nello scrivere".

Comment: @Charo “errore grossolano”, non “persona grossolana”.

Comment: La mia prima impressione è di una “supercazzola”, ma posso benissimo sbagliare. Magari è qualche locuzione burocratichese in cui si era imbattuto Fo e che qui prende in giro.